# Setting CSS property - filter: blur(x) with JS for site-inner class within genesis framework; Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, genesis

I'm trying to achieve blur effect with JS on "site-inner" class after the event of expanding the mobile dropdown menu in genesis sample theme by clicking the mobile menu button.

The button has aria-expanded attribute and I decided to use it as a trigger.

The HTML element that is being created by responsive-menus.js within Genesis Framework:

```
<button class="menu-toggle dashicons-before dashicons-menu activated" aria-expanded="true" aria-pressed="true" id="genesis-mobile-nav-primary"></button>
```

Below is the code I'm using:

```
window.onload = blurFunction();

function blurFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("genesis-mobile-nav-primary").getAttribute("aria-expanded"); 
    if (x == "true") 
    {
    document.getElementById("site-inner").style.webkitFilter = "blur(8px)";  
    }
}
```

Console returns the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null.

Uncaught TypeError: 
Cannot set property 'webkitFilter' of undefined
```

EDIT:

After removing the brackets function actually executes - but - I've added an else statement ant thats the only part that actually works. The function runs, checks the aria-expanded attribute and adds the else condition to the site-inner element to which I've added an id="st-pusher".

Here's the code:

```
window.onload = blurFunction;

function blurFunction() {
    let x = document.getElementById("genesis-mobile-nav-primary").getAttribute("aria-expanded");

    if (x == 'true') {
    document.getElementById("st-pusher").style.webkitFilter = "blur(8px)";  
    } else {
    document.getElementById("st-pusher").style.webkitFilter = "blur(0px)";  
    };
}
```

Comment: It seems an element with `id` genesis-mobile-nav-primary doesn't exist on the page. You should post your HTML too.

Comment: @Ivan86 Thanks for your response, I've just edited the post. Could you have another look at it?

Comment: where is the element with id 'site-inner' in html code?

Comment: It's right below the </header> closing tag, this is the element meant for the wordpress' main loop content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that beside the brackets used for the function the main problem was the event handler that I used. Everything works fine now after i changed it to .onclick event since the element triggering the function is a mobile-menu button. Thanks everyone for helping along :)

```
window.onclick = blurFunction;

    function blurFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("genesis-mobile-nav-primary").getAttribute("aria-expanded");

        if (x == "true") {
        document.getElementById("st-pusher").style.webkitFilter = "blur(8px)";  
        } else {
        document.getElementById("st-pusher").style.webkitFilter = "blur(0px)";  
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you did

```js
window.onload = blurFunction();
```

instead of

```js
window.onload = blurFunction;
```

thus running your function immediately instead of assigning it to be ran when the page is ready.

Comment: I've just tried this solution but it's unsuccessful in this case. Console is not reporting back any issues but the function still won't work. I'm still wondering why

Comment: It actually helped a little but didn't solve the problem, could you check the post again?